# When using docker load on a tarball I am getting an invalid argument

Tags: docker

As my question states I'm trying to use docker load on a tarball to get my image repository but when doing this it finishes with an invalid argument. I tried re-running the command with the debug flag but it doesn't show any more information. Here is what I am doing and seeing

```
MacBook-Pro:xquery-training2 john$ sudo docker -D load -i xquery-training.tar 
Password:
47d44cb6f252: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
6a7b54515901: Loading layer [==================================================>] 197.1 MB/197.1 MB
e788880c8cfa: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
1debf8fb53e6: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
72703a0520b7: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
86f8e7e36ef5: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
5e29d7d06a44: Loading layer [==================================================>] 593.2 MB/593.2 MB
cb7520e40314: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
22882bb21fb9: Loading layer [==================================================>] 181.3 MB/181.3 MB
e40605910158: Loading layer [==================================================>]   548 MB/548 MB
4f4e57271a7c: Loading layer [==================================================>] 2.048 kB/2.048 kB
fe53836f6368: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
1ebf54d9ebbe: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.402 MB/1.402 MB
6f61c40a9212: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
361fec486779: Loading layer [==================================================>] 13.82 kB/13.82 kB
4bafbf2dd399: Loading layer [==================================================>]  2.56 kB/2.56 kB
59acfc0dcab1: Loading layer [==================================================>] 3.444 MB/3.444 MB
f28cab9543cd: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
9fb69857a25e: Loading layer [==================================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB
30faed42069d: Loading layer [==================================================>] 117.4 MB/117.4 MB
4bf5210fa44c: Loading layer [==================================================>] 92.19 MB/92.19 MB
invalid argument
```

I don't know what this invalid argument is referring to nor how to fix it. I am on a mac on the latest version and this is my docker version info:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   6f9534c
 Built:        Thu Sep  8 10:31:18 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify your image was saved in the same docker version as you are attempting to load.

Saved older versions may not be compatible with newer versions of docker.